# How to add files and folders to an Azure Web App from within Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, filesystems, directory-structure

I installed the Azure extension to my Visual Studio Code and connected to my Azure Web App and I can open and edit files from my Azure Web App within Visual Studio Code without problem. What I am struggling with is how to add files and folders to my Azure Web App within VS code.
I can create a new file in VS code, but I cannot find a way to make this new file part of my Web App.

Also, dragging files from a file explorer in Windows into the Azure Web App within VS code does not work.

Is there a way to create/delete/move files and folders inside the files section of an Azure Web App that is shown in the Azure extension in VS code?

I tried to find an answer in Youtube/Google/stackoverflow but did not find a relevant solution that is applicable to my problem.

It would be great if someone could show how to manage files and folders within an Azure Web App that is open in the Azure extension of VS code to a level of detail that shows in very detail what to click/add (step by step since I do not have much experience)

Comment: What do you mean by adding files / folders to your Azure web app ? do you want static files to be copied and served by your web app ?  what is the `Build Action` and "Copy to output" property set for the files you tried to add?

Comment: A web app consists of a number of files e.g. .php files, .html files and .css files. While building a web app, you start from one file e.g. index.php, but then you need to add more files to add functionality to your app. The azure extension of Visual Studio Code shows an explorer that lists all files that are currently part of your web app, but as far as I can see there is no way to add another file like an additional php or html file. I would expect something like an "add button" that would allow for adding files as part of the web app, but cannot find any.

Comment: The way I currently do it is using an FTP client (Cyberduck) to add files to the Azure web app. Once the file has become part of the Azure web app, I can refresh the app within the Azure extension of VS and work with it. I have to believe that there must be a way for the Azure extension to do this by itself rather than having to rely on a separate FTP client.

Comment: Azure app service extension is meant for deployment, viewing logs and managing your App service from within the VS Code IDE, I don't think you can add new web page files from within it...that needs to be done to your project file depending on the language you use to develop your web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Created and deployed Azure App service from VSCode.
- Tried to add the new file / folder in VSCode and deployed to same AppService once again.

***Local folder***
[image]

- Unable to see the newly created files.

***Deployed App Folder***
[image]

You can directly add, edit or delete files/folders in Azure Web App from Azure Portal.

Navigate to the KUDU Console

***URL :*** https://YourWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

***or***
you can open KUDU console from

Azure Portal => YourWebApp => Advanced Tools => Go => Debug Console => CMD

- We have an option to create New Folder / File directly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you publish the application, the folders will be synched with the Azure Document Repository. NOTE, the folder will not be published if they are empty!